# Get n rows based on column filter in a Dataframe pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df as below.

[image]

I want the final dataframe to be like this as follows. i.e, **for each unique *Name* only last 2 rows must be present in the final output.**

[image: n]

i tried the following snippet but its not working.

```
df = df[df['Name']].tail(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Name').tail(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one more way to solve this using [`GroupBy.nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Name').nth([-1,-2]) ## this will pick the last 2 rows
```